# Encoding issue when streaming logs from AWS Kinesis to ElasticSearch via Logstash

Tags: encoding, logstash, amazon-kinesis

I've got an AWS Kinesis data stream called "otelpoc".

In Logstash, I'm using the Kinesis input plugin - see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kinesis.html#plugins-inputs-kinesis-codec).

My Logstash config is as follows:

```
input {
   kinesis {
      kinesis_stream_name => "otelpoc"
      region => "ap-southeast-2"
      codec => json { }
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
      index => "otelpoc-logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   }
}
```

I can put events to Kinesis using the AWS CLI as follows:
`aws kinesis put-record --stream-name otelpoc --data file://payload.json --partition-key 1`

`payload.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "message": "this is a test",
  "level": "error"
}
```

... but when I do this I see an error in Logstash as follows:
`Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. {:text=>"\\x99\\xEB,j\\a\\xAD\\x86+\\\"\\xB1\\xAB^\\xB2\\xD9^\\xBD\\xE9^\\xAE\\xBA+", :expected_charset=>"UTF-8"}`

Interestingly the message still get's outputted to Elastic and I can view it in Kibana as shown below:
[image]

Not sure what I should be doing with the character encoding... I've tried several things in Logstash, but no success e.g. changing the codec in the kinesis input to something like the following

```
codec => plain {
   charset => "UTF-8"
}
```

... but no luck... I tried to decode the encoded text in a few online decoders, but not really sure what I'm trying to decode from... anyone able to help?

EDIT: using v6.7.1 of ELK stack, which is quite old, but I don't think this is the issue...

Answer (score -1):

I never resolved this when publishing messages to Kinesis using the AWS CLI, but for my specific use case I was trying to send logs to Kinesis using the `awskinesis` exporter for the Open Telemetry (OTEL) collector agent - see [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/awskinesisexporter).

If I use `otlp_json` encoding, it worked e.g.

```
  awskinesis:
    aws:
      stream_name: otelpoc
      region: ap-southeast-2
    encoding:
      name: otlp_json
```